# What is the difference between EOS balance and EOS Mortgage?

Tags: balances

I'm looking at this [account](https://eospark.com/MainNet/account/heztcnjtguge) at EOSPark block explorer. As I've seen from my own account, **EOS balance** (which is currently 10 EOSes for every account I've seen) was subtracted from total EOSes (acquired at crowdsale) during the mainnet launch and the remaining amount became **EOS Mortgage**.

So what's the difference between balance and mortgage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your EOS balance is tokens that you can transfer at this moment, but 'Mortgage' actually means 'Staked'. These are reserved and you cannot transfer them until they are released.

**Your will be able to unstake your tokens when the voting reaches %15**

I believe 'Mortgage' will be used when you rent out your tokens for dApp developers for bandwidth when the main net is launched.

Answer (score 0):

The "Mortgage" also often means "Staked." - Coins that are utilized in some way you will not be able to move them unless you remove them from your CPU- or Bandwidth stake.

If your question implies how to un-stake them, you can use any wallet that supports that, i.e., the [eos-voter tool from greymass](https://github.com/greymass/eos-voter/releases).

[image: screenshot]

Go to the wallet, click update staked EOS, and select the amount you want to (un)stake. Note, it takes 72 hours to release the staked EOS before you will be able to transfer them.